# Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64 bit on Raspberry Pi 4 + RealVNC server, how?

Tags: vnc, arm, arm64, cpu-architecture

I installed the official Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 64bit image on my Raspberry Pi 4. On Raspian Buster I used RealVNC server to connect remotely to Raspberry so I want to use the same with Ubuntu but on official [RealVNC server page](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/vnc/raspberrypi/) is available .deb package for armhf architecture;
how can I user that .deb package on my arm64 system?

Comment: you need to install VNC viewer on the system you want to control from, and VNC server on the aystem you want to control. to install .deb package on Ubuntu system read https://askubuntu.com/q/40779/283843

Answer (score 3):

ARM32 is optional on ARM64. You can enable it through:

```
dpkg --add-architecture armhf
```

Afterwards, you can install the `.deb` file.
Be sure to run afterwards

```
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get upgrade; 
sudo apt --fix-broken install;
```

if needed. (Was the case for me)

Comment: I tried many times adding armhf architecture and installing the .deb manually... Installation works, but it's impossibile to connect to RealVNC server.

Comment: hi martin, i have worked on that problem half a year before, the issue is the wrong ELF class you work on 64bit Userland and the realvnc client is 32bit, there are several files to patch, i gonna restore my image tonight and continue my work on it, i let you know if i was successfull :-)